# If I buy an SSL Certificate, is this trusted in Apple without installing cert file in iOS?

Tags: ios

I created an app for iOS for a company and I want to distribute this app ad hoc over the air.

In iOS 7 and greater, I need an https site to install this app.

I created my own certificate locally and I must install my cert file via email or a direct link on iPhone to Trust this certificate and then I can install my app.

I want to know: if I buy an SSL certificate from legal seller like `godaddy` or `geocerts` and set it to my own website, do I need install a cert file on the iPhone or not?

My company's site is offline and not connected to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchasing an SSL certificate will not require any further configuration on the device, regardless of whether this is from a 'standard' Certificate Authority.

If the certificate is purchased from a standard Certificate Authority, this provides the additional benefit of verifying the company being represented by the domain, but this is tangental to the actual HTTPS requirement by Ad-Hoc distribution.

Comment: Root certificates (which are at the top of the certificate signing chain). They are typically distributed & managed by either the browser developer or the operating system. Corporate root certificate chains exist and are managed outside this set & require an additional certificate to be installed to allow the ssl cert to be trusted. Anyone selling a sitecertificate that requires a second cert to be installed before the the first will work should not be trusted.